# stopping javascript from getting executed

Tags: php, javascript, mootools

is it possible to prevent further execution of javascript?

I include some javascript scripts with php in a header (with echo ''), but there are coming some other scripts later in the page which i can not always control, so it could be that my before included (with ) mootools javascript get later overwritten by another included mootools (which then possible is an older version, or is not complete etc.)

so is there a way that I can stop the js at one point so that later js code will not be executed?

kind of like the die(); function in php, but without that it stops the page from being loaded.

Comment: no, there is no way to either stop javascript via javascript nor to prevent further scripts being brought into a page, time to refactor and clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesnt really exist. 
but you can put everything into a function and "return;" any given time to exit the function which would stop the execution of the rest of the code within the function.

super simple example in standard JS:

```
function init() {
    if(something happens) {
         return;
    }
}
init();
```

in terms of stopping the browser from executing other scripts within the page - not possible.

Comment: hm doenst really help, because i can not include the mootols library and other external classes in a function :-)

in fact there is something called window.stop(); but this is like clicking the stop loading button, and this will stop loading the page...

is there a way to prevent that one already loaded mootools libraray will be overwritten by a later included one?

Comment: sure you can, just use something like require.js ;) - sorry for being 2 years late on this haha.